# Null Error Trying to Upload picture from android phone to a php file to my computer

Tags: java, php, android, eclipse, photo

I'm getting a null error when I try to upload a picture from my phone to a php file which sends it to my computer. The file is not getting to the computer. The app works when I upload the picture it shows it but when I try to send it to my computer it sends the null error.

This line of code gives the error.

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Any ideas? Thanks! My java class is below and my php file follows.

```
 package test.example;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ImageGalleryDemoActivity extends Activity {
    InputStream inputStream;

    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            // imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); // compress
                                                                    // to which
                                                                    // format
                                                                    // you want.
                int bytes = bitmap.getWidth()*bitmap.getHeight()*4; //calculate how many bytes our image consists of. Use a different value than 4 if you don't use 32bit images.
                ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); 
                bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);

                byte[] byte_arr = byteBuffer.array();//stream.toByteArray();
                String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", image_str));

                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://192.168.1.4/Upload_image_ANDROID/upload_image.php");
                     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                     String the_string_response =
                     convertResponseToString(response);
                     Toast.makeText(ImageGalleryDemoActivity.this,
                 "Response " + the_string_response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
             .show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(ImageGalleryDemoActivity.this,
                            "ERROR " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    System.out.println("Error in http connection "
                            + e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.toString());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        ImageGalleryDemoActivity.this,
                        "ERROR " + e.getClass().getName() + " "
                                + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }

        }
    }

    public String convertResponseToString(HttpResponse response)
            throws IllegalStateException, IOException {

        String res = "";
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        int contentLength = (int) response.getEntity().getContentLength(); // getting
                                                                            // content
                                                                            // length…..
        Toast.makeText(ImageGalleryDemoActivity.this,
                "contentLength : " + contentLength, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (contentLength < 0) {
        } else {
            byte[] data = new byte[512];
            int len = 0;
            try {
                while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data))) {
                    buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len)); // converting to
                                                                // string and
                                                                // appending to
                                                                // stringbuffer…..
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                inputStream.close(); // closing the stream…..
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            res = buffer.toString(); // converting stringbuffer to string…..

            Toast.makeText(ImageGalleryDemoActivity.this, "Result : " + res,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // System.out.println("Response => " +
            // EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        }
        return res;

    }
}
```

upload image.php

```
<?php
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
     $binary=base64_decode($base);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    $file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
    echo 'Image upload complete!!, Please check your php file directory……';
?>
```

Comment: Are you saying that `httpclient` is null?  Which means that `new DefaultHttpClient()` returned null?  What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8'); ?? why define a content-type bitmap when you echo text...

Comment: Yea http client is not null. I'm getting the java null pointer exception.

Comment: If you're not sure what `NullPointerException` is, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception